# Where does LinkedIn get so much information from?

Tags: privacy, social-networking, linkedin

I've just discovered (a friend of mine told me) that LinkedIn shows (in Contacts>Connections) my full private as well as the business address. Leaving in brackets that I don't believe I have ever given this information to LinkedIn, how can I remove it now? In my profile I only have the city and the country in the address field, but LinkedIn keeps showing my friend the full address.

Comment: Some idiot contact of yours allowed LinkedIn to access their address book information to "find contacts."

Comment: Well, I wouldn't call my friend an idiot, but otherwise you're right: LI sucked not only email addresses but also information about them (me including) from her address book. And now, though information has changed, it still shows the outdated one without even clear indication that this information comes from this person. Stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you ever connect your LinkedIn account with another service like Facebook or G+ which would have access to that information?

If you dont want them to publicly show that information got to your settings->"Edit your public profile" and select what others can see

Comment: madmaze, thanks, that was the point. Only the other way around: my friend was seeing information, which was available in her Gmail contacts, so I couldn't influence it.